# This method cannot be called once the request has fully transitioned to a WebSocket request

Tags: asp.net, websocket

I've been trying to call HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute in OnMessage event implemented in a subclass of WebSocketHandler:

```
public class MySocketService : WebSocketHandler
{
    public override void OnMessage(string message)
    {
        // some activity which decides to update an area in client browser
        var html = HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("Login.ascx", writer, true);
        Send(html);
    }
}
```

But I always receive the same exception. Is there any way to make this call? Or maybe I will have to consider using WebClient?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What for? Why in the world would you execute an .aspx page in the middle of a WebSocket connection?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. The idea is to refresh an area in browser depending on any condition in server. I made it run invoking a webService to process ASCX, but I think it should be faster if it runs in this line.